# Is there a way to execute code in VB.NET after *any* event

Tags: vb.net, events

In VB.NET, is there a way to execute code after *any* event for which I have written an explicit handler, other than placing a call as the last line of each individual event handler? In ASP.NET I can put code in PreRender but there is no equivalent of that in VB.NET because there is no page life cycle.

I understand that for desktop apps the model is very different and that PreRender doesn't fit the desktop model but I hoped it would illustrate what I meant. In ASP.NET I often determine whether controls are visible, or enabled, in PreRender, after events have been processed and the underlying database has changed as a result. It seems reasonable to want to do something similar in VB.NET - multiple events can alter the underlying database, and multiple controls may need refreshed as a result, so write a routine that determines the visibility and enablement of the controls, and call it after explicitly-handled events have been dealt with.

I've tried the form validating/validated events but can't make them work.

Comment: Maybe if you explain why you must do that (i don't see any reason to do that now) we could help

Comment: Are you talking of a desktop application vs a web application? The two environments are totally different regarding on how they maintain state. As @Pikoh says, you should try to explain what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you saying that should anything happen on your form you want some code to be executed? Like `Postback`?

Comment: I don't think you understand quite how many events there are that get raised constantly.  There's the `Paint` event of the form itself and each child event for a start.  Do you really want some action to be executed on each and every event?  If you really do then you're misguided.

Comment: Usually, you only change what is needed to be change. Each specific even should know exactly what is needed. Seems like you use PreRender to update all control property no mater which event was called.